# How can I make a horizontal nav menu that on hover reveals the sub menu items and slides up above the main nav using jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, slide, nav

I want it to slide up from the bottom right about my main nav menu just like this site.  jefflewisdesign.com  I know that site is down in flash but I know that nav can be done in jquery.  thanks.

Here is how I have it so far.

```
 <div id="slidebottom" class="slide">

    <h2>Item</h2>

    <div class="inner"></div>

  </div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".inner").hide();


    $('h2').hover(function() {

      $(this).next().slideToggle();

    });

  });
```

Comment: If you know it can be done, give it a try. When you're stuck, post your code and ask a question about it, but don't expect free work from scratch. Also, if you don't know jQuery, then I suggest you start frequenting www.jQuery.com and read up on it. If you really want someone to put this together from the ground up, then I suggest you visit one of the many consultant sites out there (Plenty of programmers willing to get paid for this kind of work).

Comment: I have tried it, and I have it looking like I want it to look but I don't know if I can incorporate a nav menu in this and I don't know if I'm going about it the right way.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should solve your problem.

http://www.stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.